# Best way to rollback changes on git branch via PRs

Tags: git, github

I have branches:

`development` - current development

`staging` - for deploy development on staging server

`qa` - for deploy staging on qa server

`prod` - for deploy prod release

`master` - last stable prod version

Development process goes like this:

```
development -[Pull Request]-> staging -[Pull Request]-> qa -[Pull Request]-> prod
```

Note: Merged pull request to [staging/qa/prod] triggers deployment.

What is the best way to revert branch prod when f.e. there was a huge merge from qa?

I had a situation on prod revert that was causing merge conflicts. For example:

1. qa [PR with bug]-> prod
2. revert changes on prod to last tag (here comes the revert commit on prod)
3. Fixes goes: development -> staging -> qa -[PR with conflicts]-> prod

In step 3. When I have new code with fixed bug on qa branch, PR to prod has merge conflicts that I need to resolve locally.

Is there any way to avoid that problem or do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suggest you to follow the cycle instead of a series of PR.

currently, you have this model.

changes --> development --> staging --> qa --> prod --> master

Ideally you should have this.

changes --> development --> staging --> qa --> prod --> master -->BACK_TO-->development

this back merge can come from any branch wherever you feel current changes should not go ahead. And if all changes manage to reach master then there should be compulsory back merge to develop.

So in the Ideal cases, the last PR will just have merge commits and no file changes. but that should be ok.

In cases of Discovery of bug and a quick fix in any environment (say prod in your case), you should merge back the changes directly to development and then work on a permanent fix.

Then repeat the above process. till you get a good version on prod and finally on master.

But during backmerge to development (in cases of bug fixes) there are times when Development branch is far ahead in changes and you don't want these changes to go along with your permanent fix. In these cases you should merge back to qa/staging branch (instead of dev), work on a permanent fix there, and then follow the same process.

Following this process, you will avoid a lot of conflicts. Though you might see merge conflict only in merge-back PR (dev went ahead of prod and there were fixes in QA/prod which were not back-merged yet),  which is perfectly fine as the conflict resolution from local will go through series of tests (dev, stage,QA) before landing up in prod. The idea here is that there should not be any conflict in forward PRs.

> You just can't avoid all conflicts, but you can control when they occur.

So let it come when there is no risk involved and no urgent requirement to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit that merge issue you can simply **revert** the **revert**.

Meaning create another revert commit that reverses the initial revert on master.  You would then be able to merge QA to prod with no merge issues.

In terms of doing this better I suggest you don't use your source control as an environment provisioning tool.  Ideally the only thing that passes through environments are the artifacts that are created on the initial commit to development.